# Getting an error with docker: invalid reference format even though my command seems well-formatted

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers, tar

I'm trying to run the following command and getting an error:

```
docker run --volumes-from wp-docker-tomthedev_wordpress_1 -v `pwd`/backup:/backup/ --rm ubuntu tar -cvf /backup/wp-docker-tomthedev.tar /var/www/
```

The error it's giving me is `docker: invalid reference format.`

From what I found by googling the error, I assume the mistake relies somewhere in either the syntax or the order of the flags but I tried with `--rm` right after `run` with no more success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try it with `$(pwd)` instead of pwd with backticks. Other than that, I don't see what might be wrong with this command and I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: Strangely `$(pwd)` won't work but `${pwd}` does :/